# How to ensure URLs generated by Pyramid's route_url and route_path are valid?

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

Using URL Dispatch in Pyramid and pattern matching inside the route definition, I would like to ensure that URLs generated by `route_path` are valid and match the given route - what's the best way to do that?

This is my route definition - I want `/numbers` followed by a numeric string that's equivalent to 1 or greater...

```
config.add_route('numbers', 'numbers/{n:[1-9]\d*}/')
```

Then when I generate a route in a view for example, this is fine:

```
request.route_url('numbers', n=123)
```

It returns `/numbers/123/` which is fine...

However, if I do...

```
request.route_url('numbers', n='chicken')
```

Pyramid returns `/numbers/chicken/` which clearly doesn't match the pattern and will give a 404 when passed back to the app.

Is there a way that I can force Pyramid to check that the `n` matches the given pattern when it's generating the route? This would mean that I could be certain that `route_url` and `route_path` would give valid URLs that would work in the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a pregenerator to add custom logic when generating urls. The regex patterns in the urls have only ever been used for matching purposes.

```
def check_n(request, elements, kw):
    if not is_valid(kw['n']):
        raise ValueError('invalid url parameter')
    return elements, kw

config.add_route('numbers', 'numbers/{n:[1-9]\d*}/', pregenerator=check_n)
```

If you want to write something that validates the generated urls, it's not easy. The pregenerator doesn't know what route is being used and the route object matches paths, not kwargs. Your best bet is to wrap the route generation and validate the resulting url, instead of validating the kwargs themselves.

```
def validated_route_path(request, *args, **kwargs):
    route_name = args[0]
    path = request.route_path(*args, **kwargs)
    route_intr = request.registry.introspector.get('routes', route_name)
    route = route_intr['object']
    if route.match(path) is None:
        raise ValueError('invalid url generated')
    return path

config.add_request_method(validated_route_path)

request.validated_route_path('numbers', n='chicken') # -> ValueError
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to write a generic `check_n` function that would inspect the route and ensure any replacement marker pattern parameters matched any given regular expressions?

Comment: Gonna update my answer because it's longer than this comment box is good for.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer - testing Pyramid app routing has been a grey area for me. Your code is very helpful.